# How to upload multiple Excel files in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

This is the 1st table called `excel2` for storing English characters

[image]

This is the 2nd table called `excel3` for storing numbers

[image]

For the Excel file, there's two sheet in total, the first sheet store data of English characters and the second sheet store data of numbers.

User can choose to import multiple Excel files at the same time.

Now, when user select 3 excel file, the foreach loop is looping 3 times, but the data being inserted to the database only contain data from the 1st excel file repeatedly.

Any idea? Many thanks

```
public partial class multipleexcelimport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void importfile()
    {
        String MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=mysql_testing;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=tammy;SslMode=none";

        if (this.uploadfile.HasFile)
        {

            string[] segments = fn.Split('.');
            string fileExt = segments[segments.Length - 1];

            if (fileExt != "xlsx")
            {
                showMessage("輸入錯誤", "請上傳正確檔案xlsx");
                return;
            }

            foreach (var file in uploadfile.PostedFiles)
            {

                var fn = file.FileName;
                string newfileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + fn;

                string filepath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]) + newfileName;
                this.uploadfile.SaveAs(filepath);

                ExcelPackage xlWorkbook = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filepath));
                ExcelWorksheet xlRange = xlWorkbook.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int rowCount = xlRange.Dimension.End.Row;

                ExcelWorksheet xlRange2 = xlWorkbook.Workbook.Worksheets[2];
                int rowCount2 = xlRange2.Dimension.End.Row;

                string sql = "";
                string linkid = "";

                MySqlConnection conn = null;
                MySqlDataAdapter msda = null;

                DataSet ds = null;

                List<string> FailList = new List<string>();
                conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
                string now_time = dTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();

                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();

                            //sheet1
                            for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
                            {
                                string dates = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();


                                sql = "INSERT INTO mysql_testing.excel2 set"
                                    + " excel = ?dates;"

                                ds = new DataSet();
                                msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                                msda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dates", dates);


                            }
                            //sheet2

                            for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount2; i++)
                            {
                                string excel3 = xlRange2.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();

                                sql = "INSERT INTO mysql_testing.excel3 set"
                                    + " excel3 = ?excel3;" ;


                                ds = new DataSet();
                                msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                                msda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("excel3", excel3);

                            }

                            showMessage("alert", "success");
                            scope.Complete();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();

                        }
                    }
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tab", "$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#massimport\"]').tab('show')", true);


            }
        } 
        else
        {
            showMessage("error", "select file plz");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tab", "$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#massimport\"]').tab('show')", true);

        }
    }

    public void showMessage(string title, string content)
    {

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + content + "');", true);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        importfile();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looping thru `uploadfile.PostedFiles` but never used `file` object inside the foreach loop. `uploadfile.FileName` will always give you name of the first file. You should get the individual file names inside the foreach loop by doing `var fn = file.FileName;`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfiles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya i've tried to add var fn = file.FileName without the loop, still can't work any idea?

Comment: What happens when you use proper variable as I suggested in for each loop? Can you update the code in the question and explain the issue with it? What you mean by `can't work`?